# resizing multidimensional vector

Tags: c++, stl

How to resize multidimensional vector such as:

```
  vector <vector <vector <custom_type> > > array;
```

For example, I need array[3][5][10]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should resize all the nested `vector`s one by one.  Use nested `for` loops or recursion.

Comment: ok, such as                                              m_elements.resize(3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        array[i].resize(5);
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            array[i][j].resize(10);
        }
    }

Comment: @qutron: Yes... simple as that. :-)

Comment: You don't need to do this one by one. See my answer.

Comment: @Matt: good point - you don't *need* to, but you probably still *should* - it's more efficient than creating a large temporary then copy constructing repeatedly from it, then throwing it away....  Cheers.

Comment: @TonyD I have another point. When we resize an already initialized array(not for the first time), we must use a loop. For example, consider an `array[2][2]` which needs to be expanded to the size of {3, 3}, `resize(3, std::vector<T>(3))` does not work.

Comment: @chainro: good point... might be worth making that comment on Matt's answer...?  Cheers.

Answer (score 17):

```
array.resize(3,vector<vector<custom_type> >(5,vector<custom_type>(10)));
```

Comment: Need clarification: what exactly are 3,5 and 10 here??
Are you re-sizing a vec[5][10] to vec[3][10] ??

Comment: @aniliitb10 No; this is the example the OP asked for (please review the question). `array` is already 3-dimensional. It resizes it from whatever it was previously, to 3x5x10.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this works for OP's case of an empty vector, but if your vector already has elements, this will not resize the existing ones, so you will only get the exact desired dimensions if your existing elements are already of the desired dimensions (for instance, this will not properly resize an existing 2x2x2 vector up or a 10x10x10 down, but will work for a 1x5x10).  This is useful to set up, but not necessarily to actually "resize" an existing multi-dimensional vector.  If you need an exact size, `std::array` might be a better choice if you have C++11 or later available.

Answer (score 7):

I did it))

```
array.resize(3);
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    array[i].resize(5);
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
       array[i][j].resize(10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Or ` vector <vector <vector <custom_type> > > array(3,vector< vector < custom_type > >(5, vector<custom_type>(10)));`

Answer (score 6):

see also [Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html)

`Boost.MultiArray provides a generic N-dimensional array concept definition and common implementations of that interface.`

Answer (score 2):

I would make a custom container containing a vector of vectors (of ... per dimension) and resize with resize-functions per dimension.  This way you can put the invariant of equal size per dimension in one place.  The actual resizing can then be done in a loop according to dimension.
There will be a bit of work involved in making public what needs to be accessed (operator[],...)