# Global Variables Empty C++

Tags: c++, global-variables

I've got to use three global variables:

```
int maxX = 0;
int maxY = 0;
vector<vector<char>> mapVector(maxX, vector<char>(maxY));
```

I'm initializing maxX and maxY in one fucntion

...

```
maxY = newString.size();
maxX = linesCount;
```

...

and the last one in another:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < maxX; i++)
{
for (size_t j = 0; j < maxY; j++)
{
if

 (mapBuffer[y] != '\n')
{
mapVector[i][j] = mapBuffer[y];
y++;
}
if ((mapBuffer[y] == '\n') || (mapBuffer[y] == '\0'))
{
for (size_t x = j + 1; x < maxY; x++)
{
mapVector[i][x] = ' ';
}
y++;
break;
}
}
}
```

So, the thing is, when I try to access the "vector> mapVector(maxX, vector(maxY));" from some other fucntion, the variable appears to be empty, but the maxX and maxY are not. That's weird. Why do you think that happens?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
int maxX = 0;
int maxY = 0;
vector<vector<char>> mapVector(maxX, vector<char>(maxY));
```

intialises the vector of vectors with size maxX and maxY respectively. It happens on line 3 when maxX=0 and maxY=0. If you change maxX or maxY later it won't change anything.

To alter the size of mapVector use `resize` or add elements via `push_back`

EDIT:

Try this

```
vector<vector<char>> mapVector(0,vector<char>(0)); //intialise here: doesn't make any difference using maxX=0 or not
```

then at the top of your function AFTER you have set maxX and maxY do this

```
mapVector.resize(maxX);
for (int i=0;i<maxX;i++){
    mapVector[i].resize(maxY);
}
```

or more concisely

```
mapVector.resize(maxX,vector<char>(maxY));
```

Comment: I did resize it. But it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

you should resize the 2 dimensional vector with a loop.
resize mapVector to maxY
then use loop to resize each entry in mapVector to the size of maxY

ref : [resizing multidimensional vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311953/resizing-multidimensional-vector)

Comment: mapVector.resize(maxX);
 for (int i = 0; i < maxX; ++i)
  mapVector[i].resize(maxY);
Where do I do that exactly? In the main or in the current function?

Comment: ilf you change maxX and maxY only in one function, resize mapVector in that function :)

Comment: I did resize it in that function, still when I try to access the 2d array from a different function, maxX and maxY have a value and the array does not

Comment: without the full code, it's difficult to see where the issue could be.
so try to resize in the fucntion where you try insert the data
to compare the behavior