# Resize recursive nested vector in template

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I'm trying to make a template function that resizes a nested vector in all it's dimensions.

Pretty much like this: [resizing multidimensional vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311953/resizing-multidimensional-vector) , but for an arbitrary nr. of dims.

(I suppose) The function would (at least) accept a reference to the vector (or `vector<vector<T>>` or `v<v<v<T>>>`, etc.) and a vector with the desired sizes. I now also have in index in the sizes vector, but it's probably not needed.

So far, this is what I ended up with (could be completely wrong):

```
template<typename V> void resize(vector<V> & V1, vector<int32_t> t, int32_t index) {
    int32_t current_size=t.at(index); 
    cout << "resize dim [" << index << "] to size " << current_size <<endl ;
    ++index;
    if (index < t.size()) {
        // for each element ??
        // for( int i = 0 ; i < V1.size(); i++ ) { resize (V1.at(i), t, index); } // doesn't work
        // for( auto const& e : V1 ) { resize (e, t, index); } // doesn't work
         // resize( V1, t, index); // recursive call, works, but doesn't do anything
    }
```

I'd like to avoid copies of V1 or any of it's content. I'm not sure if there is a way with an iterator or for loop that passes references. If not, there probably needs to be a forth input to keep the index of V1?

Btw., I'm skipping the first dim on purpose, it is already the correct size.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what are "all dimensions" for you in a vector?

Comment: Hayt: one dimension for each nested vector. So vector<T>, one dim, vector<vector<T>> two dims, etc. .

Comment: @Wiebe you could post your code as an alternative answer (I don't think in is a good manner to post an answer inside a question on SO)

Comment: @W.F. ok, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for something like this (this is c++14-compliant solution, similar one would be a little bit more tricky for c++11 but still possible):

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <class NestedVectorElement, class Tuple>
void nested_resize(std::vector<std::vector<NestedVectorElement>> &v, Tuple &&t);

template <class VectorElement, class Tuple>
void nested_resize(std::vector<VectorElement> &v, Tuple &&t);

template <class Vector, class Tuple, size_t... Is>
void nested_resize_impl(Vector &v, Tuple &&t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
   v.resize(std::get<0>(t));
   for(auto &nv: v) {
      nested_resize(nv, std::forward_as_tuple(std::get<Is + 1>(t)...));
   }
}

template <class NestedVectorElement, class Tuple>
void nested_resize(std::vector<std::vector<NestedVectorElement>> &v, Tuple &&t) {
   nested_resize_impl(v, t, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value - 1>{});
}

template <class VectorElement, class Tuple>
void nested_resize(std::vector<VectorElement> &v, Tuple &&t) {
   v.resize(std::get<0>(t));
}

int main() {
   std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> matrix;
   nested_resize(matrix, std::make_tuple(3, 2, 3));
   matrix.at(2).at(1).at(2) = 0; // at gives you an access only if element exists else throws an exception
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It did help fix some details in my code, and I got it working.

Comment: Is your suggested code more efficient (or otherwise better) then the working solution I posted?

Comment: @Wiebe glad to hear it :)

Comment: @Wiebe apart for IMHO a little bit more cumbersome way of invocation I actually think your solution would work with the same time complexity

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
    template<typename V> void resizer(V & V1, vector<int32_t> const & t, int32_t index) {}

    template<typename V> void resizer(vector<V> & V1, vector<int32_t> const & t, int32_t index) {
        int32_t current_size=t.at(index); 
        V1.resize(t.at(index) );
        ++index;
        if (index < t.size() ) {
            for( auto & e : V1 )  {
                resizer (e , t, index);
            }
        }
    }
```

But this is actually a bit better, since we're not needlessly iterating over the last dimension's elements:

```
    template<typename V> void resizer(vector<V> & V1, vector<int32_t> const & t, int32_t index) {
        int32_t current_size=t.at(index); 
        V1.resize(t.at(index) );
    }

    template<typename V> void resizer(vector<std::vector<V>> & V1, vector<int32_t> const & t, int32_t index) {
        int32_t current_size=t.at(index); 
        V1.resize(t.at(index) );
        ++index;
        if (index < t.size() ) {
            for( auto & e : V1 )  {
                resizer (e , t, index);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is that each instance of the template needs to generate code for two possibilities: the last dimension of the multidimensional vector, and all other dimensions of the vector. And in the case of the latter, it is necessary to recurse over the following dimensions of the vector, which will lead to an obvious compilation error in the case of the former.

This requires specialization:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename V, typename iter_type>
class resize_dim {

public:
    static void resize(V & V1,
               iter_type b, iter_type e)
    {
        if (b == e)
            return;

        V1.resize(*b);
    }
};

template<typename V, typename iter_type>
class resize_dim<std::vector<std::vector<V>>, iter_type> {

 public:

    static void resize(std::vector<std::vector<V>> & V1,
               iter_type b, iter_type e)
    {
        if (b == e)
            return;

        V1.resize(*b);

        ++b;

        for (typename std::vector<std::vector<V>>::iterator
                 vb=V1.begin(),
                 ve=V1.end(); vb != ve; ++vb)
            resize_dim<std::vector<V>, iter_type>::resize(*vb, b, e);
    }
};

template<typename V>
void resize(V &v, const std::vector<size_t> &dimensions)
{

    resize_dim<V, std::vector<size_t>::const_iterator>
        ::resize(v, dimensions.begin(), dimensions.end());
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> v;

    std::vector<size_t> d;

    d.push_back(3);
    d.push_back(3);
    d.push_back(3);

    resize(v, d);

    std::cout << "Ok" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The sizing vector, giving the size of each dimension should match the number of dimensions in the vector. Extra sizes are ignored. Fewer sizes result only in the leading dimensions getting resized.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to figure out which solution to use now, or which pasts for each solution. And you are right, there is room for mistakes here, so at some point it's probably better to make a class to embed the nr. of dims, dim sizes and nested vectors, in...